# ggplot2, how to control for linetype and colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have four time series variables, I want to plot them all in one graph. I want to plot two variables in solid line and the other tow in dashed line. The solid lines will be in red and blue, the dashed lines will be in black and brown. I was wondering if anyone could help with coding? I've the following for now:

```
data1 = melt(data, id = 'Year')
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Year, y = value,colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  ylab(label="Index") + xlab("") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue","black", "brown"),labels = c("ES","LS","Wax","EP"))+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.15,0.85),legend.title=element_blank(),legend.background = element_rect(fill=NULL))
```

This code produced a graph with solid lines only.

Comment: It's essential to know the structure of `data1` for this question to be answerable.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, it is time series, four variables each has 214 annual observations. Thanks.

Comment: Google "ggplot2 linetype".

Comment: It's easier to help with plotting questions if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data we can copy/paste into R to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assumed I could recreate something that looks alike data1 with this

```
data1=data.frame(Year=1:100,value=rnorm(100),variable=factor(floor(4*runif(100)+1)))
```

What you need to change your linetype is the *scale_linetype_manual()* function.

For instance in your problem, my answer would be

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Year, y = value,colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable)) +
  ylab(label="Index") + xlab("") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid","dashed", "dashed"),labels=c("ES","LS","Wax","EP")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue","black", "brown"),labels=c("ES","LS","Wax","EP"))+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.15,0.85),legend.title=element_blank(),legend.background = element_rect(fill=NULL))
```

Which produces :
[image: Graph with legend]

Comment: Great, many thanks. How do I put the legend names? Can you please edit your answer by putting legend names so that the answer is complete, I will then mark it as the answer.

Comment: Done ;)
If I may add, you basically just have to put the same labels for each *scale_XXX_manual()* .